# Replication of Header

Tags: header-footer

I would like to replicate the header as shown on the pic. My problem is related to the fact that I do not manage to center the headline exactly in the middle of that 3cm range and I have difficulties with 5 units of space between the page number and the headline itself. I would be very grateful for any possible help. Thank you very much! [image]

Comment: It would be nice to have a MWE which illustrates what you've tried to do.

Comment: Also, what are the units for the `spacebar (5x)`?

Comment: @A.Ellett Sorry for being late with the answer, spacebar (5x) means that I simply must have 5 units of space inbetween

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility. The three rules start at the top of the type block, their heights are 2.9cm (just to go a little short from the top margin of the paper), 1.75cm and 1.25cm.

The header is centered in the 0.5cm space. What you mean by "spacebar 5x" is unclear; I used 1.66667em, which is equivalent to five spaces in the current font (the normal spacing is 0.33333em).

I also set the bottom margin to 3cm, equal to the top margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  includehead,
  top=0pt,
  left=4cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=3cm,
  heightrounded,
  headheight=1.75cm,
  headsep=1.25cm,
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][0.5cm]{\textwidth}
  \small
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  A Constant Recontracting Model of Sovereign Debt%
  \hspace*{1.66667em}%
  \thepage
  \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}
Some text for showing the first text line
\smash{\rule[\topskip]{0.4pt}{2.9cm}}
\smash{\rule[\topskip]{0.4pt}{1.75cm}}
\smash{\rule[\topskip]{0.4pt}{1.25cm}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @A.Ellett I made a screen capture

Comment: @A.Ellett A remainder from an experiment, I'll remove it; thanks for noting.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% clear about what all the dimensions mean.  I took the `4cm` to be the left margin and `2cm` to be the right margin.  I have no idea what you wanted for the bottom margin.

Here's a MWE that begins to create something like what you're specifying:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%--------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry
  {
    %% margins
    top=3cm,
    left=4cm,
    right=2cm,
    %% header
    headsep=1.25cm,
    headheight=0.5cm,
  }
%%--------------------
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
%%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
%% commands to control the contents of 
%% headers and footers
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\makebox[0pt][r]{A Constant Recontracting Model of Sovereign Debt}%
       \hspace*{2em}%
       \thepage}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
%%--------------------
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is it, thanks a lot, I need to check it, I will let you know!

Comment: thank you very much! I have inserted the code and everything works perfectly! I appreciate your support! Thank you!